# When to teach daughter to dry herself after urinating

Tags: pre-schooler, age-appropriate

My daughter is five years old and my wife is out of town for a while. While I am taking care of her on a daily basis, she seems old enough to dry herself after using the toilet.

Are there any generally accepted guidelines on when a young girl is ready to take care of her own post-urination drying needs?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of any standard guidelines, as all kids are different, but she should definitely be able to do this by age 5.

We had both of our daughters doing this from about 3 and a half. At first they needed some guidance, eg "always front to back" but it should be relatively straightforward for them.

Answer (score 2):

I bought [Princess Pollys Potty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006YLZ2ZM) for my daughter.. she's drying herself from 3 1/2. All kids are different, but assuming she's not wearing nappies anymore, then she should be able to do this

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a set age, but once a child is doing relatively well at potty training, I think it's a good idea to start letting her at least practice wiping, and you can help. Then once you see she's doing a fairly good job at it, she can do it herself all the time.